# Change the color of background of code of Matlab

Tags: listings, color

I use the following code in LaTeX to input the code Matlab there but I want to change the color of the background:

```
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \lstdefinestyle{customc}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=L,
xleftmargin=\parindent,
 language=Matlab,
  showstringspaces=false,
 basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
 commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
 identifierstyle=\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{orange},
 }

  \lstdefinestyle{customasm}{
 belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
 frame=L,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
   language=[x86masm]Assembler,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
    }

   \lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}
```

How can I do that to look like that in LaTeX report?

[image: output]

Comment: Relevant: [Inserting MATLAB code in the appendix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75116/5764)

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The background colour of listings can be set with the `backgroundcolor` key. To get the specific colour, you can open your screenshot in for example Gimp and sample the colour used in the Matlab cells, then use this to define a custom colour:

```
\definecolor{MatlabCellColour}{RGB}{252,251,220}
```

Then add this to your `customc` style.

```
backgroundcolor=\color{MatlabCellColour}
```

Complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,xcolor}
\definecolor{MatlabCellColour}{RGB}{252,251,220}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=L,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=Matlab,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  backgroundcolor=\color{MatlabCellColour}
 }


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=customc]
for k = 1:1000
  disp(k^2)
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Educ Sorry, I must be blind. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: it's okay now thanks so much could you pleasse tell me what is the name of color in the background of matlab in my picture

Comment: @Educ I have no idea, but give me a minute, I'll open the screenshot in Gimp and sample the color.

Comment: The color in RGB model: `\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{252,251,220}`.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Thanks but how can i put it in latex to have the same color as matlab

Comment: @Educ Torbjørn T. has just edited his answer showing you how.